# Curl not writing cookie and http code 404, why?

Tags: cookies, curl

I want to curl cookies
cookie file is created but empty, why?
And agent_http_code value: 404, why?
Thanks.

```
$url ="https://example.com";
$xmlfile = '/home/*******/public_html/2.xml';
$cookie_file = '/home/******/public_html/cookie.txt';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('action-xmlagentxmlfile'=>'@' . $xmlfile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
if (file_exists($cookie_file) && filesize($cookie_file) > 0) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Some context wouldn't go amiss, either.